# Can I configure a server to use a different network conection for Upload/Download

Tags: networking, windows-server

Can I configure Windows Server to use a different Network Connection for Uploads and Downloads?

I would be content with knowing what this is called, or terminology associated with it.

I would like to run a server from home; my cable connection has maximum of 1.5mbps upload. A wireless (LTE) offers synchronous data transfer at great speeds, but it is expensive, unless it is used for uploads only.

Comment: In the realm of professional sysadmin, such a thing could be possible with enterprise network equipment, however, in your realm, I don't know. You may have more luck asking on SuperUser (which your post might just get migrated to).

Comment: I thought to ask at ServerFault because I assumed it was a professional option, available only on professional hardware/software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid not as the uploads and downloads will need to be coming from the same IP address.
I'm sure if you had a high spec firewall you could ask one of the networking guys the best way to route the traffic but if I'm understanding your question correctly you can't do what you are trying to do.

Thanks

D